# emplace_back in a list from a unique_ptr

Tags: c++

This does not compile

```
  std::list<int> l;
  std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>();
  l.emplace_back(std::move(p));
```

The internal storage of lists are `_List_node`, which are simply back and forth pointers to the underlying data, here `int`. So a list could steal the internal pointer of a `unique_ptr` and emplace it back.

In my complete use case I have a list of objects bigger than `int`, and I use the move constructor like this

```
  l.emplace_back(std::move(*p));
```

But that's slower than stealing the pointer of the `unique_ptr`, because many fields of my underlying type are copied.

Why don't lists accept moving from `unique_ptr` and is there another container that does ?

Comment: `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` can do that.

Comment: If using `std::list` is not mandatory, do as @super suggested

Comment: @super `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>` is actually what I already have, and what I want to change. One of the reasons is `unique_ptr` can be `nullptr`, which makes my code uselessly complicated with many tests of `nullptr`. It would be cleaner with a container of objects.

Comment: The data - in this case `int` - is enclosed within the `_List_node` (at least for all common implementation), so the `int` is part of the `_List_node` and not at a separated memory location.

Comment: @V.Semeria well if the problem is that one then your question should be completely different :)

Comment: @Moia My full problem is more complicated than a single stack overflow question can handle. I had to focus on a specific part of the problem, and indeed I had overlooked the storage problem explained by eerorika below.

Comment: @V.Semeria I understand, but if nullcheck is an issue maybe you could use a vector of `std::reference_wrapper` or `gsl::not_null`, but it's indeed another question, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So a list could steal the internal pointer of a unique_ptr

No, it couldn't. A list allocates nodes where the element is stored. An object of element type won't be of use to it.

Only thing `std::list` can steal elements from is another `std::list` of same type.

In order to avoid the move, either create the object as an element of a list in the first place, or don't attempt to store it in one. Keep the object in one place.

In cases where moving is fast - which is for most types, then `std::move(*p)` is just fine.

Comment: Do you mean that the pointers `_Next` and `_Prev` of `_List_node` must be in the previous 128 bits, just next to where the node's data is stored ?

Comment: @V.Semeria Not literally, but the idea is along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

A typical implementation of a `_List_node` looks like this:

```
template<typename _Tp>
    struct _List_node : public __detail::_List_node_base
    {
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
      __gnu_cxx::__aligned_membuf<_Tp> _M_storage;
      _Tp*       _M_valptr()       { return _M_storage._M_ptr(); }
      _Tp const* _M_valptr() const { return _M_storage._M_ptr(); }
#else
      _Tp _M_data;
      _Tp*       _M_valptr()       { return std::__addressof(_M_data); }
      _Tp const* _M_valptr() const { return std::__addressof(_M_data); }
#endif
    };
```

And `__alignment_membuf` does look roughly like this:

```
  template<typename _Tp>
    struct __aligned_membuf
    {
      struct _Tp2 { _Tp _M_t; };

      alignas(__alignof__(_Tp2::_M_t)) unsigned char _M_storage[sizeof(_Tp)];
    };
```

So the data stored in a list is fully enclosed within the `_List_node` as the `_M_data`/`_M_storage` member variable (there is only one memory allocation for `_List_node` and no additional one for `_Tp`).

A list node, therefore, does not have a pointer to the data it manages but contains it.

Due to that, there is no way to steal the pointer, the type that is stored in a list has to be always moved or copied.